# random string generator in multiple lines

Tags: vb.net

How can I make more than one random string in multiple lines? For example:

```
waee
wefe
sety
rtgs
```

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form3
    Dim pool As String = ""

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        pool = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._"

        Dim count = 0
        TextBox1.Text = ""

        Dim cc As New Random
        Dim strpos = ""

        While count <= TextBox2.Text
            strpos = cc.Next(0, pool.Length)
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & pool(strpos)
            count = count + 1
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Loop, reset value to nothing, rest to random value

Comment: This isn't VBA, it seems to be VB.NET, they are not the same thing.

Comment: Not VBA, so changed to VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to do is make sure `TextBox1` has the `Mutliline` property set to `True`.

The second thing to do is check the `Options` declarations. There are indications this file is set for something other than `Option Strict` or `Option Infer`, and that is not good. If `count <= TextBox2.Text` isn't causing a compile error, something is very wrong.

Then you can do this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pool As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ._"
    Dim cc As New Random()

    Dim Length As Integer = CInt(TextBox2.Text) - 1
    Dim result(Length) As Char
    For count As Integer = 0 To Length
        result(count) = pool(cc.Next(0, pool.Length))
    Next

    TextBox1.Text &= (New String(result)) & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

Comment: if I want to generate the whole list of 4 letter length how?